# animate() not working for the object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a SVG inside an object tag that I want to animate using jQuery's animate() but I can't seem to make it work. I am trying to change the image position by 20%. I have tried the exact animation on other tags such as IMG or DIV and it works fine. I don't want to use css() to do this. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<object class="animation" id="picture" data="images/toy.svg"></object>
```

CSS

```
.animation {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;
 left: 5%;
 width: 30%;
 height: 30%;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(initPage);
function initPage(){
    $("#picture").animate({"top":"20%"}, "slow");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a div and animating that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add object to div and animate div.

HTML

```
<div class="animation" id="picture">
    <object data="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRK-yM30mBX0HBwS0htU0MejWfxwabj4X3LhbG-sp8_JzsaxFnt"></object>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jSsZn/186/)